# Vega-lite: pie chart legend sorting seems not work

Tags: vega-lite

I have this [json definition](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAZgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoVYdulQgCcIAa0y0GzZGwC+67gBsAhgE9MMlAG1QAW10z5eEIX0AHTChBWwIbhUJGASrrpwVCgAjBxaIJhQkAFQSKg82hDG8fCY2nQuNjqYCJEZ8cSE2s7IICDhlEniKVjpLlDl3PZO9RDmJLrajXaMmIS6tql1pWgeIJUy1aBD+SANFf1gNsiypJhNjiUgAI6kukRw-cRozuGEEBDaxA6m07WzWXaHxS4AwnqUlGPNW1BtHV0tHc0rNRtwYElLNUPAA6YIwb7PLZoTprb6bFy7faFXTHU4AXTOSJcABViUCQJZrLYfi5vAAPcTguDaLqlABGeiWYxk-kCX2QwQATBpuJFoiQ4vhLklBvdMmNirkoPlQIUXqVuhMpiAZvVurTSn92lBOgbMIy5SCXGDdZDcS5OHCERsWqUsQcjnATgbev0rcMQLbtQHZvMpItlqt1nYMe69p7cd7Tk0Llc4DdkGZdfLSo91Vt3rpPui3XN-qbAZxgYHbRCZFDHc7EUVkajnK6th6cXjyoSmsTSgBBSv6ShwSgAAgAqlBDpP2fpJ5REi0mryoJR6+ZbjmrkYXAAKOi40jmGFoScAPknoQAlH31PjuCf-fFTeYtq-dABadkADmCYIAHY2DAMAADYgOA+FwP-GAoN0dghVCODMDYf9ugAEkoMBeksFwxEIBxKGQAB6MiTgQXQYQQQ5GFIdkYTgCAyNw-DdEonJf20Q5MEogBWGEhRhNgYQAK0qBoX1xYs+gFUBvz-QCQLAyDoNgsB4MQ5DUK09DMKzUAGkFbhZw-TA6GQW8UC4EBlhANgfwEycAFIxlGZAAE4ABYYX-HyWCFHzgP-NhgggmCBJ8ikTKFMyoAsqybLUbgHIEn9QjcjzWBhCD-yFLzggE4ChWAmDSsK2LWASpLrOCWy0pcUIfxFbLuE8sSIIEoV-wg7qBKC3yIPYATquQHzat0T9koa1L7JcEUfx8th2qDWyYR8gT-2AryWGAoLQJ8nzALG6s5hQASppm+rGoW0oVsyjg1s6mEWAglDgKggKoJQ4IvIgp9NCAA), in which I sort the color using a numeric field (`n` in the image below).

[image]

But in the output the legend is sorted by a textual field (`k` in the image above).

How force legend sorting by `n` field, ascending?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must add sorting in [encoding](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Rq5uGbswUrNQ1m81hMnhLk4yNRBzxJzOFyucBubsY40mftD0IWVRDawdm22u32diB+KTRJJbvujzgz2QZmdb1KWTsdtKv10-1xRygbU94Jb-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)